# How can i render a Vuex state depending on a function triggering?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I've seen that there are a couple of questions like this but I could not get any progress with them, so I'll make my own.

The thing is as follows.
I have a state "allCountries" which is an array and initially is filled with 250 countries objects. I'm rendering these countries in my home component correctly, the thing is that I want to filter when clicking in a button the countries for the continent that the button represents. For example, if the button says "Europe", I want to receive all the countries where the property "continent" is Europe.

I'm achieving this with the following code:

```
const store = createStore({
state: {
    allCountries: [],
    filteredCountries: [],
    countryId: {},
},

mutations: {

    filterByContinent(state, payload) {
        let countries = [...state.allCountries];
        state.filteredCountries = countries.filter(
            (country) => country.continent === payload
        );
    },
},
```

The problem is that i don't know how to render the filtered countries when the button is clicked, in the vuex dev tools i can see how the "filteredCountries" state is filled with the correct continent countries when clicking.

I was trying this but is not working:

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- <p class="homeTitle">COUNTRIES:</p> -->
    <ul class="countriesBox" v-if="allCountries">
        <li
            v-for="country in allCountries"
            :key="country.id"
            class="countryCard"
        >
            <br />
            <router-link
                :to="{
                    name: 'CountryDetail',
                    params: { id: country.Id },
                }"
                class="countryName"
                >{{ country.name }}</router-link
            >
            <br />
            <p class="countryContinent">{{ country.continent }}</p>
            <br />
            <img
                :src="`${country.flagImage}`"
                alt="country flag"
                class="flagImage"
            />
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="countriesBox" v-else-if="filteredCountries">
        <li
            v-for="country in filteredCountries"
            :key="country.id"
            class="countryCard"
        >
            <br />
            <router-link
                :to="{
                    name: 'CountryDetail',
                    params: { id: country.Id },
                }"
                class="countryName"
                >{{ country.name }}</router-link
            >
            <br />
            <p class="countryContinent">{{ country.continent }}</p>
            <br />
            <img
                :src="`${country.flagImage}`"
                alt="country flag"
                class="flagImage"
            />
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="backAndForwardButtons">
        <button>&#10094;</button>
        <button>&#10095;</button>
    </div>

    <FiltersBar />
</div>
</template>
```

I'm mapping correctly the states with

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import store from "../store";

export default {
    name: "HomePage",
    computed: {
        ...mapState(["allCountries"]),
        ...mapState(["filteredCountries"]),
    },
};
```

if anyone can help I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a getter checking if there is a `.length` to `filteredCountries`. If not, it defaults to `allCountries`, like:

```
countries(state) {
  return state.filteredCountries.length ? state.filteredCountries : state.allCountries
}
```

Then in your component, you don't have to replicate the logic to render two separate lists coming from two different data sources. Just have to use one data source which in this case I called `countries`

Comment: You are a master! Thank you, your answer solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

your store getter for filtred countries could be something like this

```
filteredCountries: (state) => cont => {
      return state.countries.filter(country=>{
       return country.continent===cont
    })
}
```

well maybe the code is not as accurate but I think the idea remain the same

as you can see there is extra argument to the `filteredCountries` getter, that is where your selected continent goes

then in your component

```
data(){
   return {
       cont_filter:"europe"
   }
}
```

hopefully changing the value to the `cont_filter` is not a problem, because that is what you want to change on button click. now you can use that simply like this

```
    <li v-for="country in filteredCountries(cont_filter)"
                :key="country.name">
        {{country.name}}
   </li>
```